# External Constraints in CPLEX IDE

Tags: constraints, cplex

I have a list of constraints for a CPLEX model, in a file called "constraints.txt".

I want to import "constraints.txt" into the "subject to {}" block of my CPLEX model, but I do not know how.  I realize that I can take contents of the file and "paste into" the "subject to {}" block, but that seems a little sloppy.

Does anyone know how to import these external constraints into the CPLEX IDE?

I looked into writing a script, but learned that an ILOG script does not work in the "subject to {}" block.

Answer (score 0):

You can use include

Suppose you have constraints.mod

```
subject to
{

x<=2;
}
```

then

```
dvar int x;

maximize x;

subject to
{
  
}

include "constraints.mod";

execute
{
  writeln("x=",x);
}
```

gives

```
x=2
```